# MySQL Workbench. Way to generate foreign keys in forward engineering as alter table statements?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there any option in MySQL forward engineering which can generate FOREIGN KEYS as ALTER TABLE STATEMENT?

Comment: Can't you just find how to do a normal alter table statement and add it?

Comment: Database has at least 30-50 foreign keys. Somebody drop foreign keys from working project. And I Don't want to add them manually. That's why I'm asking about built in functionality of MySQL workbench

Comment: I have already done this task by parsing of sql code, but interested if this functionality exists as native option of MySQL Workbench

Comment: If someone drops a foreign key constraint from a working project then it should be removed from the create table script, vise verse. You shouldn't need a tool to create a database, a single script should be sufficient.

Comment: Not in my situation. Different skills of developer team where I'm working. Few developers are lazy to read about "how can I make my life easier with FK" - and when they saw message like "cannot do something : a foreign key constraint" they prefer to drop this key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward engineering in MySQL Workbench is the process of applying a modell as a whole on the target server. Existing objects are "overwritten".

In your case use the synchronization feature (a 2-way merge) that allows to apply individual changes via ALTER TABLE etc. on the target db. At the same time changes in the target schema that are not yet in the model are taken over, so both model and server are in sync after that.

[image]